# SQL Installation Error : directory is compressed or is in a compressed directory

Tags: sql-server

> Unable to install SQL Server (setup.exe). Exit code (Decimal):
> -2054422498Exit message: The specified directory, "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server)", for the INSTALLSHAREDDIR parameter is not valid because this directory is compressed or is in a compressed directory. Specify a directory that is not compressed.

I have already unchecked the `Compress contents to save disk space` option in advanced properties of the folder as suggested in another similar questions here.

Please help me figure out the solution to install SQL Server.

Comment: Maybe you need to check the parent folders too? ..."because this directory is compressed or is in a compressed directory"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I asked in the question, I had already unchecked the `Compress contents to save disk space` option in advanced properties of the folder however the same changes were required in the parents folder too (topsail's comment).
So I repeated the same steps as shown MBuschi's answer to the parent folder too and it worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

You have to remove compression.

[image]